# How to error trap in Angular where I can't go to the Next Page

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Hey Im kind of new to Angular and trying to get this part right so I can finish my coding. I'm trying to error trap where it won't allow me to go to the next page I want the required choices validating for each form when submitted or go to the next page.

veteran.html

```
<div class="container">
<h4>Military Veteran</h4>
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(veteranForm)" #veteranForm="ngForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="veteran">Are you a military veteran?</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="veteran" required  value="Y" #veteran ngModel> Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="veteran" required  value="N" #veteran ngModel> No&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>

        <div> 
            <small>
                Please click on one of the option buttons above before submitting form!
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <pre></pre>
    <footer>
        <button id="exit" class="btn btn-danger" >Exit</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="navigateIfYes(veteran.checked)"> Next </button>
    </footer>
</form>
```

veteran.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-veteran',
   templateUrl: './veteran.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./veteran.component.css']
})
export class VeteranComponent {

   constructor(private router: Router) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {}


   navigateIfYes(value: boolean) {
     this.router.navigateByUrl(!!value ? "/veteran-snap" : "/snap");
   }

   onSubmit(form: NgForm){
    console.log(form);
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a fast way to do that:

In the veteran.ts file:

```js
// add the following class property (needed to show the error message)
errorMessage?: string;

// Update the function
// Now you ave the whole input element instead of just the checked prop
// ng-untouched is a class added by angular that flags the input "untouched". 
// As soon as you touch it, the class disappear. You can check whenever the input has been touched by looking at this class
navigateIfYes(input: HTMLInputElement) {
  if(input.classList.contains('ng-untouched')) {
    this.errorMessage = 'Select one option'
  } else {
    this.errorMessage = undefined
    this.router.navigateByUrl(!!input.checked ? "/veteran-snap" : "/snap");
  }
}
```

in veteran.html

```html
<!-- Add this line where you want to show the error message -->
<p *ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</p>

<!-- Update the navigateIfYes funciton by passing vateran instead of veteran.checked -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="navigateIfYes(veteran)"> Next </button>
```

Comment: Nevermind I got it should this form always submit? Like when I click next and go to the next page how do I make it submit the previous page or do it submit?

Comment: You should submit the form only when inputs are valid

Comment: Please flag the answer as accepted if it fits your needs :)

Comment: I will just trying to figure this out on my next page